# Facebook share button and custom text

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to make facebook share button which post custom text on the wall or news feed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customize message field on Facebook Share](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591655/customize-message-field-on-facebook-share)

Answer (score 94):

We use something like this [use in one line]:

```html
<a title="send to Facebook" 
  href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOUR_TITLE&p[summary]=YOUR_SUMMARY&p[url]=YOUR_URL&p[images][0]=YOUR_IMAGE_TO_SHARE_OBJECT"
  target="_blank">
  <span>
    <img width="14" height="14" src="'icons/fb.gif" alt="Facebook" /> Facebook 
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Do you know how to make this link open in a popup or modal window? Just can't find a method that works, it's not as simple as using some generic popup window code...

Comment: More effective then the answer on top.

Comment: @tvgemert: Try `<a class="facebook" target="_blank" onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'Facebook', 'width=640,height=300')" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=YOUR_URL">Facebook</a>` etc.

Comment: Perfect, this also works for hashbang urls!

Comment: @Mateng, is there a way to do open it in a lightbox/colorbox instead of a "new window" with code similar to yours?

Comment: @hockey2112 Use a lightbox that supports iframes and put the URL into the iframe.

Comment: Whaaat? How has this not been selected as the answer? This worked perfectly and the little addition by @Mateng worked like a charm too! +1 for each of you

Comment: This no longer works.

Comment: change the '_blank' to '_window'

Answer (score 30):

To give custom parameters to facebook share its better to give only the link and facebook gets its **Title + Description + Picture** automatically from the page that you are sharing. 
In order to "help" facebook API find those things you can put the following things in the header of the page that you are sharing:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

[Check here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/)

If the page is not under your control use what **AllisonC** has shared above.

### **For popup modalview type behavior:**

Use your own button/link/text and then you can use a modal view type of popup this way:

```html
<script type= 'text/javascript'>
$('#twitterbtn-link,#facebookbtn-link').click(function(event) {
var width  = 575,
    height = 400,
    left   = ($(window).width()  - width)  / 2,
    top    = ($(window).height() - height) / 2,
    url    = this.href,
    opts   = 'status=1' +
             ',width='  + width  +
             ',height=' + height +
             ',top='    + top    +
             ',left='   + left;

window.open(url, 'twitter', opts);

return false;
});
</script>
```

where twitterbtn-link and facebookbtn-link are both ids of anchors.

Comment: If URLs are identical, is the data from meta properties being cached by facebook? Or can I put in, e.g., individual POST data with every page view?

Comment: I didnt get what you mean by that.

Comment: I just came across this. I have like/share code on my homepage that is set to like/share the facebook page associated with my business. It seems to be ignoring the facebook meta tags I have on the page. Anyone run into this issue?

Comment: This method does not seem to work anymore. I think the only way to achive a customised Facebook share button (with your own text, title and image) is to use the Facebook SDK.

Comment: Great solution, to make it also modern do `if( window.open(.....) ) event.preventDefault();` instead of just `return false;˙ ! - that way it only prevents default behaviour (link open) when window was opened - provides fallback when it was not...

Answer (score 12):

Youtube Uses this function for sharing

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=87741124305&href=https://youtube.com/watch?v=3hxE7Af98AI&feature=share&display=popup
```

The following one is a dated solution where you can
use this function derived from link provided by IJas

```
function openFbPopUp() {
    var fburl = '';
    var fbimgurl = 'http://';
    var fbtitle = 'Your title';
    var fbsummary = "your description";
    var sharerURL = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=" + encodeURI(fburl) + "&p[images][0]=" + encodeURI(fbimgurl) + "&p[title]=" + encodeURI(fbtitle) + "&p[summary]=" + encodeURI(fbsummary);
    window.open(
      sharerURL,
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
    return  false;
}
```

Or you can also use the latest FB.ui Function if using FB JavaScript SDK for more controlled callback function.

refer: [FB.ui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/)

```
    function openFbPopUp() {
        FB.ui(
          {
            method: 'feed',
            name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
            link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/',
            picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
            caption: 'Reference Documentation',
            description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
          },
          function(response) {
            if (response && response.post_id) {
              alert('Post was published.');
            } else {
              alert('Post was not published.');
            }
          }
        );
    }
```

Comment: this FB.ui is perhaps the most reliable approach, plus you can load this script at the bottom of your page with the rest of your javascript, and load in jquery variables / selectors as values.  Thanks for posting this.

Comment: @blackhawk ...but FB.ui also requires app_id - that is not always an option... :)

Comment: @Bravesh B Searching the documentation related to FB.ui you linked I couldn't find the params you pass to FB.ui like picture, caption, description. Could you tell me where did you find them?

Comment: @Ferex you can find the params here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

Comment: As of April 18, 2017, the following parameters are no longer supported by Graph API versions 2.9 and higher. For versions 2.8 and lower, the parameters will continue working until July 17, 2017.

Comment: @BhaveshB i have use your code and i want to share only description but not working please check it here 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/57680369/10748606

Answer (score 9):

You have several options:

1. Use the standard FB Share button and set text via [Open Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) and meta tags on your page.
2. Instead of Share, use [FB.ui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/)'s stream.publish method, which let's you control the URL, title, caption, description and thumbnail at run-time.
3. Or use http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php with appropriate parameters.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the latter? What are these parameters?

Answer (score 6):

You can customize Facebook share dialog box by using asynchronous JavaScript SDK provided by Facebook and setting up its parameter values

Have a look at the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#share_button').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      FB.ui(
        {
          method: 'feed',
          name: 'This is the content of the "name" field.',
          link: 'URL which you would like to share ',
          picture: ‘URL of the image which is going to appear as thumbnail image in share dialogbox’,
          caption: 'Caption like which appear as title of the dialog box',
          description: 'Small description of the post',
          message: ''
        }
      );
    });
  });
</script>
```

Before copying and pasting the below code you must first initialize the SDK and set up jQuery library. Please [click here](http://viratgaywala.blogspot.in/2014/05/how-to-add-facebook-share-button-to.html?view=classic) to know a step by step how to set information on the same.

Answer (score 3):

This is the current solution (Dec 2014) and works quite well. It features

- open a popup window
- self-contained snippet, doesn't require anything else
- works with or without JS. If JS is disabled, the share window still opens, albeit not as a small popup.

`<a onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'Share on Facebook', 'width=640, height=536')" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=href=$url&display=popup&ref=plugin" target="_window"><img src='/_img/icons/facebook.png' /></a>`

$url var should be defined as the URL to share.

Comment: it doesn't work on my case where my page starts with https...?

Comment: This answer is invalid now, as Facebook has stopped supporting any other parameters in sharer

Answer (score 0):

This is  a simple dialog feed that Facebook offer's.
Read here for more detail
[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

Answer (score -1):

you could combine AllisonC's idea with `window.open` function:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

```js
function openWin(url) {
    myWindow = window.open(url, '', 'width=800,height=400');
    myWindow.focus();
}
```

And then on each link you call the openWin function with the right social net url.

Answer (score -3):

Try this site http://www.sharelinkgenerator.com/. Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue where people are looking for custom title/descriptions

Comment: with your solution there is not possible to put custom text with facebook please give another solution