# Angularjs site with hashbang to share on Facebook

Tags: angularjs, facebook, share, hashbang

I have an angularjs website with hashbang in the url(which cannot be removed at this stage of the product). The blog pages have links to share the post to social websites.

If I try to share the post on Facebook, Facebook gives an error saying that the link might be broken. I faced the same problem for twitter tweets. But I replaced #! with %23 and it works fine. Is there a similar way for facebook? Thanks in advance.

Comment: turning on html5mode might be helpful.

Comment: Like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893288/how-to-handle-facebook-sharing-like-with-hashbang-urls