# facebook share button going to take image it self in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i'm want to implement custom facebook share button and i'm going to use following link

[Facebook share button and custom text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138780/facebook-share-button-and-custom-text/6138879#6138879)

where in [images][0] tag i gives my own image but still face book share button going to take image it self from website. Can i set that image? if yes then how to set that image ?

Thank you

Comment: And why don't you show us your code?

Comment: Do you want to put the new image into the Facebook button with javascript or asp.net ?

Comment: hi, i edits my code, is it correct?

Comment: If it works, then it will be correct. At least it seems so...

Comment: that's fine if it works correctly with javascript