# Post image to Facebook page with description

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I am trying to find a way to post an image along with a description to a Facebook page. The idea is for users to submit a photo and a description to a website. Once the image is uploaded the user can then share the uploaded image with the description they've added on to a Facebook page.

I'm not sure if this is possible to do. I guess it's something Facebook's Graph API might help or maybe something like from this question ([Facebook share button and custom text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138780/facebook-share-button-and-custom-text?answertab=votes#tab-top)) would be enough:

```
<a title="send to Facebook" 
  href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOUR_TITLE&p[summary]=YOUR_SUMMARY&p[url]=YOUR_URL&p[images][0]=YOUR_IMAGE_TO_SHARE_OBJECT"
  target="_blank">
  <span>
    <img width="14" height="14" src="'icons/fb.gif" alt="Facebook" /> Facebook 
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: that code is NOT facebook graph api , everything you want to do is definitely possible with the graph api , but you're going to have to read and follow a tutorial on it

Comment: Those parameters are deprecated!