# Custom message in FB share dialog

Tags: facebook

I am trying to customize a user's message when he/she shares a link on our site via FB similar to this one:

[image]

I have read [Facebook share button and custom text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138780/facebook-share-button-and-custom-text) but it 
only changes the small texts below and not the main "status". Any links on how to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to change/prefill the message text in the FB.ui dialogs, and it is not allowed according to the platform policy. The message must be 100% user generated and prefilling is not allowed:

https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

> 2.3: Ensure that all content in the user message parameter is entered by the user. Don’t pre-fill. This includes posts, messages, comments, and captions.

The only possibility to fill the message parameter is to use an API call to `/me/feed` with the `publish_actions` permission - but still, you are not allowed to prefill and `publish_actions` has to go through a review process. Facebook will never approve it if you prefill, of course.

Comment: could you take a look on this. I have an issue that is related to this API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66654709/facebook-sdk-send-method-in-reactjs