# Facebook share shows different data

Tags: html, facebook

I have added the following tag to [a website](http://supportseekers.info/):

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="Support Seekers" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Support Seekers is an online support group where members can share personal problems in an anonymous and safe forum. Everyday our counseling psychologist will post professional recommendations regarding each issue - which is free expert help!" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://fminteractive.co/projects/supportseekers/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/ss-newlogo.png" />
```

Still when I share it on Facebook, the title, description and image are different than what is mentioned in here. Why is it so?

Note: I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138780/facebook-share-button-and-custom-text).

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: @CBroe: I wish I could upvote this. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and debug the URL, this will clear Facebook's cache of the meta data and force Facebook to scrape the page again.

Look out for errors of missing OG tags as sometimes these can affect what Facebook outputs.